# What should be the order of installing different versions of MS Visual Studio and MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, installation

I have recently started working for an organization that uses a lot of in-house developed legacy systems and I have been given a new machine to install all the tools required to maintain and modify said systems as needed. The machine is running Windows 10 Professional and came presintalled with .NET Framework 4.6.1.

Now my question is, what should be the exact order of installing different versions of MS Visual Studio and MS SQL Server starting from VS 2008 and SQL Server 2008 R2 to VS 2017 and SQL Server 2016 so that all the tools perform as expected?

The reason for asking this question is that a colleague tried installing the tools in the obvious chronological order in which they were released but found that some of the features of the older versions stopped working after the installation of the newer ones.

Comment: *but found that some of the features of the older versions stopped working after the installation of the newer ones* - I haven't seen that happen, but can you give any example of such features?

Comment: SSDT 2017 can deploy to SQL Server 2012+. So if you have servers ranging from 2008 to 2016 all you need is SSDT 2017 and BIDS (for 2008).

Comment: ... and SSMS 17.x to connect to any of the SQL Server versions.

Comment: @Nisarg The features not working include Intellisense in SSMS 2008 R2 and Report Viewer in VS 2010.

Comment: @Ess_TeeYou don't need SSMS 2008 and VS 2010. You only need SSMS 2017, and (like i said above) SSDT 2017 and BIDS. Back compatibility is a wonderful thing. Personally, if you've installed every SSMS since 2008, and several versions of VS, I'd actually suggest removing the ones you don't need (Which will probably be VS 2010, VS 2013, VS 2016 and SSMS 2008, 2012, 2014 and 2016).

Comment: @Larnu I'll give your advice a try then. Thanks

Comment: @Ess_Tee, does your issue is solved or not? If not, please feel free to let us know.